# Build modal dialog from scratch with JavaScript for IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a modal dialog box in JavaScript.  I have it working in Firefox but not IE with some code like this...

```
$(window).bind('scroll resize', function (e) {

    var $this = $('.popup');

    var d = document;
    var rootElm = (d.documentelement && d.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat') ? d.documentelement : d.body;
    var vpw = self.innerWidth ? self.innerWidth : rootElm.clientWidth; // viewport width 
    var vph = self.innerHeight ? self.innerHeight : rootElm.clientHeight; // viewport height 

    $this.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        left: ((vpw - 100) / 2) + 'px',
        top: (rootElm.scrollTop + (vph - 100) / 2) + 'px'
    }).show();

});
```

This works perfectly in FireFox, but not in IE (not targeting ie6)

**The Problem**

The initial placement is fine in IE, but when i go to resize, the div does not move back to middle of the view port.  I verified that the resize and scroll both are being triggerd, but the placement is off in IE.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/LpuDh/

Comment: Why do you need to build from scratch? Your using jQuery and jQuery UI already has a modal dialog, which could be added to your project?

Comment: So what's the incorrect/undesirable IE behavior?

Comment: @john - jquery ui is very intrusive.  
@surreal - resizing does not move the image to the right place vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the viewport height and width... used the jquery stuff and it works fine.

```
 $(window).bind('scroll resize', function (e) {

        var $this = $('.popup');

        var d = document;
        var rootElm = (d.documentelement && d.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat') ? d.documentelement : d.body;
        var vpw = $(window).width(); // viewport width
        var vph = $(window).height(); // viewport height

        $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            left: ((vpw - 100) / 2) + 'px',
            top: (rootElm.scrollTop + (vph - 100) / 2) + 'px'
        }).show();

    });
```